# Compare two dates not working

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to compare `start date` and `end date` but it working for same month. But I am enter two different month is not working.

For ex: I am enter `start date= 23/12/2013` and `End date=06/12/2013` it will working but I am enter `Start date = 23/12/2013` and `End date=01/01/2014` it will give same error.

model:

```
    public function _date(){
        $startDate = strtotime($this->input->post('start_date'));
        $endDate = strtotime($this->input->post('end_date'));

        if ($endDate >= $startDate)
            return True;
        else {
            return False;
            $this->form_validation->set_message('compareDate', '%s should be greater than Contract Start Date.');
        }
        return False;
}
```

Controller:

```
    function date_validation(){
    $isDate = $this->mdl_education->_date();
    $data['emp_id'] = $this->input->post('emp_id',TRUE);
    if($isDate)
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Please Enter valid Date ');
        redirect("education/form/".$data['emp_id']);
    }
}



$this->form_validation->set_rules('end_date', 'End Date', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_date_validation');
```

What is solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$startDate = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $this->input->post('start_date')));
$endDate = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $this->input->post('end_date')));
```

and [documentation for strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime).

**Update:** Important note from above document

*Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.*

Answer (score 0):

Another option is **[DateTime](http://php.net/datetime)**

You must supply the proper format you have set or it will return `false` example is `m/d/Y`

```
$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y',$this->input->post('start_date'))->format('U');

$endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y',$this->input->post('end_date'))->format('U');
```

You could format it first as `timestamp` before comparing.

> **timestamp** is Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)

```
 if ($endDate >= $startDate)
 {
    return True;
 }else
 {
    return False;
    $this->form_validation->set_message('compareDate', '%s should be greater than Contract Start Date.');
 }
```